# Definition of Mapping

Tags: elementary-set-theory, intuition

Some formal characterization is seems very abstract for me.

For instance:

> *Let $X$ be a finite set of alternatives. We denote by $\chi$ (respectively, by $B$) the collection of all non-empty subsets
>   (resp.,of all binary subsets) of $X$. A choice function is a mapping
>   c:$X$→$\chi$ such that c(A)∈ A. That is, a choice function c assigns
>   to every non-empty set A ⊆ X a unique element c(A)∈A.* (Apesteguia & Ballester 2013)

What is the best way to understand this kind of characterization. Namely, i interpret this statement as below:

Let's say: $X$ ={a,b,c,d,e,f,g}

$\chi$={(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)}

What is exact interpretation of mapping statement at there?

Thanks

Comment: @GitGud: This is all about finite sets, *really* nothing to do with the axiom of choice. :-)

Comment: Your formal statement is incorrect: it should say $c:\chi\to X$, or else $c(A)\in A$ is incorrectly typed.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was too careless with my reading.

Comment: @GitGud: It's Saint Patrick's Day, I can't stay mad at you. :D